# Hacking quiz image

Tags: visual

This is an image from a hacking quiz. It has a hint (kind of)

> Being successful is on your hands.
>   If want you to come up with a solution, you should look closer.
>   *(That's what it says before the pic)*
>
> [image: 7.jpg]

It's from a hacking contest, so it's something pretty advanced

Comment: Is it from an ongoing contest or is the contest over?

Comment: it's over, I couldn't firgure out and the won't give the answer for another week

Comment: @YunusEmre Do you know the answer?

Comment: @Techidiot  yeah

Comment: Are (any of) the tags [tag:computer-puzzle] and [tag:steganography] applicable?

Comment: Was the image removed, or is that part of the puzzle?

Comment: I think I remember seeing this when it was newer, and the image was still there then. I think maybe this should be closed since plainly the puzzle is now missing an essential part.

Comment: (So I'm VTC as unclear, which I think is the nearest close-reason we have to "unanswerable because an essential part is missing".)